# Emulator process system isn't responding

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to load my app which was loading fine the other day. However now whenever I launch the emulator I get the process system isn't responding.

I have read some posts and they suggest changing the resolution. Through Run > Edit Configurations and then go to the emulator tab. However in my andriod studio (2.3.3) there isn't a emulator tab so I can't seem to change the resolution.

**My Emulator**

Pixel API 25        1080 × 1920: xxhdpi 25  Android 7.1.1 (Google APIs) x86 1 GB

Comment: There was recently an emulator update (through the SDK). That's probably why it changed. You could try giving it more RAM and see if that helps

Comment: in the AVD I can see the RAM is 1536mb, is this what I want to increase? And if so by how much?

Comment: Enough. I use 4 gigs but that's to get it to run as closely to a real device as I possibly can. For you, 2 gigs or 2.5 could be enough to get it to run at all.

Answer (score 6):

For me I did these step to solve it Through AVD Manger> Edit this AVD and then go  and I changed Graphics: Automatic to Software and it solved the problem.